# c++ returning a custom struct type - error

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, return

I have started learning C++ today and am currently having some problems.

I have a custom struct that I called data:

```
struct data{
int x, y, l;
};
```

It a simply struct with 3 variables.

Next I run this recursive function. Albeit, it done not matter what it does since printing out the final return statements yields the correct result.

```
data finds(int x, int y, int length, string s){
    //cout << length << endl;
    int nx = prev(x, s);
    int ny = next(y, s);
    if(nx != -1 && ny != -1 && s.at(nx) == s.at(ny)){
        finds(nx, ny, length + 2, s);
    }
    else{

        cout << x << y << length << endl;
        data vals;
        vals.x = x;
         vals.y = y;
         vals.l = length;
        return vals;
    }
}
```

The cout statement in this function yields

```
068
```

which are the numbers I want. However, when I try to print the results of this functions like so:

```
464078426865241
```

which is obviously wrong.

My question becomes: how do I properly return a struct to yield the correct values.

Also you probably want some runnable code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct data{
    int x, y, l;
};
int next(int i, string s){
    //cout << s;
        //cout << j;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < s.size(); j++){
        if(isalnum(s.at(j))){
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int prev(int i, string s){
    //cout << s;
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        //cout << j;
        if(isalnum(s.at(j))){
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
data finds(int x, int y, int length, string s){
    //cout << length << endl;
    int nx = prev(x, s);
    int ny = next(y, s);
    if(nx != -1 && ny != -1 && s.at(nx) == s.at(ny)){
        finds(nx, ny, length + 2, s);
    }
    else{

        cout << x << y << length << endl;
        data vals;
        vals.x = x;
         vals.y = y;
         vals.l = length;
        return vals;
    }
}

int main(){
    s = "1233321";
    data val;
    val = finds(3, 3, 2, s);

    cout << val.x << val.y << val.l;





}
```

Comment: Turn up your warning level and you should discover some undefined behaviour.

Comment: not compilable on vs2012

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the function that did the recursion:

```
return finds(nx, ny, length + 2, s);
^^^^
```

Otherwise not doing so results in undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks for the tip but that doesn't seem to fix it. But, I think I know the problem now!